# How to debug multiple API from 2 solutions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

We have multiple projects contained in 2 different solutions in Visual Studio.  My API project in Solution A will do HTTP request to another API project in Solution B but the problem is that I can't seem to get the debugger to work as the breakpoints in Solution B project doesn't get hit.

Comment: Have you attached to the w3wp process?

Comment: Could it be that both solutions are different processes which are started separately? If yes, why don't you start 2 visual studios and debug each project. I don't think Visual Studio can handle more than one debugger at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable this option explicitly in visual studio.

**If you notice, when running on debug, in the debugger you will have two processes you can debug, those are your two solutions.**

to do that:

1. Choose Debug, Attach to Process. On the Attach to Process dialog box, select the process from the Available Processes list, and then choose Attach. -- **or `ctl+alt+p`**
2. choose your process for the second solution from the list and attach it as well, in order to debug it.

there is a whole article regarding this in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx) and also in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785374/visual-studio-debug-multiple-project-at-the-same-time).